# Filling additional columns of an internal table with additional data by SELECT statement? Can this be done?

Tags: select, abap

```
SELECT matnr ersda ernam laeda 
FROM mara 
INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE gt_mara 
UP TO 100 ROWS.
```

At this point I have 100 entries in the itab `gt_mara`.

```
SELECT aenam vpsta pstat lvorm mtart
  FROM mara
  INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE gt_mara
  FOR ALL ENTRIES IN gt_mara
  WHERE matnr = gt_mara-matnr AND
        ersda = gt_mara-ersda AND
        ernam = gt_mara-ernam AND
        laeda = gt_mara-laeda.
```

At this point I have 59 entries. Which makes sense. This code is buggy, because it might be modifying the selection criteria at run time.

Anyway what i intended was this: select the first 4 fields of the table at one point, and then select the other 5 at some other.

Of course, this is just an example. Perhaps the second select would be done on a different table with the same key or with a different number of fields.

So can this even be done?
Are there more efficient methods to achieve this than what comes to my mind by default (redoing the complete select) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either `SELECT` everything you need right away (which is the preferred solution if the data comes from the same table) or `SELECT` the additional stuff later (which is a good idea if the stuff comes from a different table that is not used for the first selection). For assembling the result set, the database usually needs to access the entire dataset anyway, so it doesn't really hurt to select some additional fields - in contrast to hitting the database again with a massive `SELECT` statement (if the `FOR ALL ENTRIES` table gets large). Also bear in mind that - depending on the kind of processing you're doing - the contents of the table might have changed in the meantime. If the database transaction (LUW) ends (which is always the case between dialog steps), you loose the database-level transaction isolation.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I think the essence of your question is more about whether you can update certain unfilled fields in an internal table directly through a second select statement.

The answer is no.  Your second select statement would replace the contents in table `gt_mara`, so you would be left with an internal table where the first 4 fields are blank, and the last 5 are filled.

The best you could do is something like this:

```
SELECT matnr ersda ernam laeda 
  FROM mara 
  INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE gt_mara 
  UP TO 100 ROWS.


SELECT matnr aenam vpsta pstat lvorm mtart
  FROM mara
  INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE gt_mara2
  FOR ALL ENTRIES IN gt_mara
  WHERE matnr = gt_mara-matnr AND
        ersda = gt_mara-ersda AND
        ernam = gt_mara-ernam AND
        laeda = gt_mara-laeda.

loop at gt_mara2 into ls_mara.
  modify gt_mara from ls_mara transporting aenam vpsta pstat lvorm mtart 
    where matnr = ls_mara-matnr.
endloop.
```

This is obviously quite inefficient, which is why you would always try to make the database do as much of the work for you before you bring the data back to the application server.  Obviously if the data is coming from the same table selecting it all in one go is going to be your best option.  In most cases even if the data is in different tables you would be better off creating a view or using a join.

In rare cases it is necessary to loop at your internal table to fill in some fields that were not available to you when you did the original select.